# Как выделить память под процесс?

Tags: c++

Подскажите, какой максимальный объем памяти может предоставить под процесс система и как это можно проверить ?
Разве под процесс можно выделить больше чем одну страницу ?

Comment: Какую страницу?

Comment: У меня ОСРВ QNX

Comment: Какой QNX? 4.25? 6?

Comment: [ulimit](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.0SP3/neutrino/utilities/k/ksh.html#ulimit), [getrlimit](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/neutrino/lib_ref/g/getrlimit.html), [setrlimit](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/neutrino/lib_ref/s/setrlimit.html)

Answer (score 1):

У каждого процесса есть своя собственная виртуальная память, именуемая адресным пространством, в которой исполняется код этот процесса и его данные, на которые этот код ссылается и которыми управляет. 32-битные процессы используют 32-битные указатели на адреса в виртуальной памяти, которые создают абсолютный верхний предел в 4 ГБ (2 в 32-ой степени) на объем виртуальной памяти, которую 32-битный процесс может адресовать.

Comment: Думаю стоит добавить что это ограничение можно преодолеть см. [PAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension)